# Passing a property in a generic way?

Tags: .net, generics, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, sqlcedatareader

I'm reading an SqlCeDataReader and assessing values like so:

```
if(reader["abc"] != DBNull.Value)
    Abc = (int)reader["abc"];

if(reader[dude] != DBNull.Value)
    Dude = (string)reader[dude];

int Abc
{
    get;
    set;
}

string Dude
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

And I wanted to condense it to one function but with a minimum amount of code, ideally I'd like something like:

```
Dude = GetField( "dude", reader );
```

And have it work itself out returning NULL if there's nothing to return. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an extension method like:

```
public static string GetSafeString(this IDataReader reader, string name)
{
    int ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal(name);
    return reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : reader.GetString(ordinal);
}
```

and use:

```
Dude = reader.GetSafeString("dude");
```

However! Personally I would suggest looking at something like dapper-dot-net, which will handle all the materialization code *for you*, so you just write:

```
string region = "North";
var users = connection.Query<User>(
    "select * from Users where Region = @region", // <=== query
    new { region }                                // <=== parameters
).ToList();
```